# Best way to import JSON data from Eventbrite API to Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, eventbrite

Please excuse this amateur question. I'm building a web app and would like to extract Eventbrite's JSON data sorted by address onto my embedded Google maps.

Right now I have the data in my console using fetch. How can I display this data on Google Map as markers?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Start here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

The code sample provided in this documentation is formatted for GeoJSON but you should be able to use the nodes from your EventBrite JSON *if* they provide coordinates. If coordinates are not part of your source JSON you will need to make a separate API call to Google Maps API [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)